# Python Regex for URL doesn't work

Tags: python, regex

I'm using python and trying to use a regex to see whether there is a url within my string. I've tried multiple different regexes but they always come out with 'None', even if the string is clearly a website.

Example:

```
>>> print re.search(r'/((?:https?\:\/\/|www\.)(?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)*[-a-z0-9]+.*)/i','www.google.com')
None
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: remove leading `/` and trailing `/i`

Answer (score 1):

What about, as in [Python Regex for URL doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27576717/python-regex-for-url-doesnt-work) , switching to something like:

```
r'http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+'
```

For a detailed survey of many, many regexes validating URLs, see https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex ...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if a string is an URL you can use:

```
print re.search(r'(^(https?://|www\.)([a-z0-9-]+\.)+([a-z0-9]+)$)','www.google.com', re.I)
```

If you want to verify if a string contains a URL, you only need to remove the ^ and $ patterns:

```
print re.search(r'((https?://|www\.)([a-z0-9-]+\.)+([a-z0-9]+))','www.google.com', re.I)
```

Remember: re.I is for case-insensitive matching, the '^' matches beginning of line and $ matches end of line.

Answer (score 0):

The grammar for a valid URL has been explained here in this [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator). Based on that this regex can match a string if it has valid URL.

```
^((?:https?|ftp):\/{2}[\w.\/]+(?::\d{1,4})?\/?[?\w_#\/.]+)
```

And in case if you want to keep the `scheme` part of the URL optional.

```
^((?:https?|ftp)?(?::\/{2})?[\w.\/]+(?::\d{1,4})?\/?[?\w_#\/.]+)
```

Output

```
>>> re.search(r'^((?:https?|ftp)?(?::\/{2})?[\w.\/]+(?::\d{1,4})?\/?[?\w_#\/.]+)','www.google.com').group()
'www.google.com'
>>> re.search(r'^((?:https?|ftp)?(?::\/{2})?[\w.\/]+(?::\d{1,4})?\/?[?\w_#\/.]+)','http://www.google.com').group()
'http://www.google.com'
>>> re.search(r'^((?:https?|ftp)?(?::\/{2})?[\w.\/]+(?::\d{1,4})?\/?[?\w_#\/.]+)','https://www.google.com').group()
'https://www.google.com'
```

You can see a detailed demo and explanation about how it work [here](https://regex101.com/r/mD5fP7/1).

Answer (score 0):

i've used the following regex in order to verify that the inserted string is a URL:

```
r'((http|https)\:\/\/)?[a-zA-Z0-9\.\/\?\:@\-_=#]+\.([a-zA-Z]){2,6}([a-zA-Z0-9\.\&\/\?\:@\-_=#])*'
```